# ImageMagick displacement does not work as expected

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm using latest ImageMagick with PHP and this is my code:

```
$diplacementmap = new Imagick('displacement.png');
$android = new Imagick('android.png');

$android->compositeImage($diplacementmap, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DISPLACE, 0, 0);

echo $android;
```

For some reason, I'm not getting expected results. Why could it be?

[image: imagick COMPOSITE_DISPLACE results]

**Both files separately:**

Android - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYbYX.png

Displacement map - https://i.stack.imgur.com/6g4v9.png

Comment: What happens when you swap the images?

Comment: @jrswgtr just a mess of different shades of grey.

Comment: I think your actual result is far more artistic than the expected one 

Comment: Please provide your input images **separately** for testing. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've added them. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your displacement values to 10,10 in ImageMagick or Imagick. When you set the arguments to 0,0, you may be getting some larger default.

For example in command line:

Input:

[image]

Displacement map:

[image]

```
convert android.png displacement.png -define compose:args=10,10 -compose displace -composite result10.png
```

[image]

or at 20

```
convert android.png displacement.png -define compose:args=20,20 -compose displace -composite result20.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I added this `$android->setImageArtifact('compose:args', '5,5');` and now it's just what I needed.